# RSA Libraries Python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, asymmetric

To work with RSA encrytion in Python, I have done extensive research and found several libraries including pycrypto, pycryptodome, etc. However, by using the simple code below.. it all works and it concerns me that I'm missing something????

This is my basic code that seems to work easily in Python 3.7 for RSA asymmetric encryption. It's simple.

```
import rsa

(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(1024)

 message = b'my top secret'

 crypto = rsa.encrypt(message,pubkey)
 decrypt = rsa.decrypt(crypto,privkey)
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Why do you think something is missing?

Comment: it's too simple. I'm happy to run with it but all other examples ( with other libraries) seem to be very detailed and complex, relatively speaking.

Comment: Well, it's easy to encrypt and decrypt inside a single piece of code, but developing a entire system is quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. Anyway, baring any serious flaws, this is good enough for me. Thanks or your responses.